# Dirichlet convolution of two lists

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

The Dirichlet convolution of two arithmetic functions f,g is defined by

$f\ast g(n) = \sum\limits_{d|n} f(d)\ast g(n/d)$

How can I get the Dirichlet convolution of two lists?

For example: Input: {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
and return: {1, 3, 4, 7, 6, 12, 8, 15, 13, 18}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{l1, l2} = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}
MapThread[DirichletConvolve[n, #1, n, #2] &, {l1, l2}]
(* {1, 3, 4, 7, 6, 12, 8, 15, 13, 18} *)
```